# Python converting a text file into a json object

Tags: python, json

I am not new to programming, but I am very new to python.  I don't yet completely understand Python's data structures. Below is my problem.

Given a txt file containing the text:

> FEB 5
>
> ACTION COMICS #28
>
> BATWING #28
>
> CAPTAIN AMERICA #16
>
> ...
>
> FEB 12
>
> ABE SAPIEN #10
>
> AMAZING SPIDER-MAN MOVIE ADAPT #2
>
> BATMAN #28
>
> ...

I want to create a JSON object that looks like:

> {"ACTION COMIC #28":"FEB 5", "BATWING #28":"FEB 5", "CAPTAIN AMERICA #16":"FEB 5", "ABE SAPIEN #10":"FEB 12", "AMAZING SPIDER-MAN MOVIE ADAPT #2":"FEB 12", "BATMAN #28":"FEB 12"}

So far I have gotten to the point where I have two equal length lists that each contain the corresponding comic book titles and dates.  For example, say I have the two lists below:

```
comic_book_titles = ["ACTION COMICS #28", "BATWING #28", "CAPTAIN AMERICA #16", "ABE SAPIEN #10", "AMAZING SPIDER-MAN MOVIE ADAPT #2", "BATMAN #28"]
dates = ["FEB 5", "FEB 5", "FEB 5", "FEB 12", "FEB 12", "FEB 12"]
```

How do I get the JSON object described above?  Note, that I can't just enter in:

```
import json
data = [{"ACTION COMIC #28":"FEB 5", "BATWING #28":"FEB 5", "CAPTAIN AMERICA #16":"FEB 5", "ABE SAPIEN #10":"FEB 12", "AMAZING SPIDER-MAN MOVIE ADAPT #2":"FEB 12", "BATMAN #28":"FEB 12"}]
json.dump(data)
```

Because I am getting the data from a text file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import json
data = dict(zip(comic_book_titles, dates))
json.dumps(data)
```

[More info about `zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip)